# Access a struct i unmanaged C code

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I have a pile of C code (.exe) which is unmanaged (not compiled with /clr). I would like to access/manipulate a C struct in the C code from a managed wrapper in C++/CLI prefarably as a dll. I am new to C++/CLI, what do I have to do to make this happen?

Comment: Your .exe is not "a pile of C code". It's an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the address of that struct, it's not going to happen.

And knowing the adderss depends heavily if it is defined as a global variable, a local variable in a function or allocated dynamically?

Comment: The struct is defined as a global variable.

Comment: Does the C code with the globally defined struct have to be compiled with option /clr?